# Office 365 / Outlook Issue While Pushing Contacts through Rest API

Tags: outlook, office365, office365api

I have done outlook integration to push contacts to the outlook account

But for some users(Specifically Office 365 users), it is not pushing contacts to their account.

What Could be the issue ??

I'm Using Common Rest API

Answer (score 0):

Office 365 users email ids are slightly different from other users. Please retrieve all email ids and use regex expressions or string replace functions to modify those specific email ids and then push the data into account.

Comment: I think You completely Misunderstood My Question Or I Didn't Understand Your Answer. I mean to Say that when We call Common Rest API. It will Ask us to login to Outlook/Office365/Personal Account and using that Token We Can Push Contacts to that Particular Account  but for Some office365 Accounts Contacts Are Not Pushing